# Remote access to Windows applications from Linux without limiting to desktop area

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, rdesktop, xming

For example **xming** (for access Linux/Unix X Window application on Windows host) I be able to select **multiwindow mode** when each Linux windows show as resular MS Windows application:

[image]

But I don't know if this possible in revert direction: MS Windows application on X without limiting them to desktop area...

[image]

**rdesktop** have *some* support for requested functionality through [SeamlessRDP](http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/) but currently has limitations (despite fact that also require proprietary components...):

```
Windows 7 and Windows 8 are not supported.
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? At this point it appears you want a list of products that might meet your requirements which wouldn't be on topic to Super User. I would use a virtual machine like vmware and use unity mode to acomplish a seamless remote desktop requirement.  Have you even tried to see if SeamlessRDP works with Windows 7 because if it works with Windows Vista there isn't a technical reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: **Windows 7 and Windows 8 are not supported.** is official statement from project home page...

Comment: I don't want a complete list of products. I am interesting only in one product... Thanks for suggestion about *vmware + unity mode*. I will be glad to see equivalent feature in VirtualBox... Thnks for info +1

Comment: An incomplete list of products is still a list which wouldn't be very constructive.  I am aware what the project says is and isn't supported it also clearly has **NOT** been updated recently.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly RDP *does* support seamless windows mode. I believe that it was introduced at least by the time of XP if not earlier. Windows 7 & 8 versions of RDP both have the capability.

So you need to have an RDP client that supports it. As Ramhound has said, I would give SeamlessRDP a go to see if it will work.

Alternatively, you will need to look for another tool.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is hard part to find *another tools*. +1

Comment: @gavenkoa - If you can't find other tools why place the burden on us to find and suggest them?  If you have a problem we can help solve it of course.

Comment: @Ramhound You are right. +1